# LibreOffice Writer: How to take a table one line up when it is in the second line?

Tags: libreoffice

**In a LibreOffice Writer I opened an RTF document in which I have the first line empty and the second line containing a table.**

[image]

### My question

How could I take the table one line up, so it would be in the first line?

If it was Microsoft Word I would just mark the table, cutting it and pasting it in the first line but when I mark a table, cut it and paste in LO Writer, it will cut **only the text in the table**, and not the entire table itself.

Thus, I need a way to move / cut the entire table into the first line.

### Why I ask this:

Well, hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> with the cursor on the first line isn't enough to take the table up into the first line (it isn't possible in MS Word as well, to be honest).

Comment: How to improve the question?...

Comment: I have no trouble moving the cursor to the first (empty) line and deleting it, thereby moving the table up one line.

Comment: How do you delete it? By `Backspace`? To me it doesn't delete it...

Comment: I use the Delete button.

Comment: @Jos You just broke my habit of years to use only `Backspace` when deleting in documents. Would you feel comfortable to construct an answer? Because it just did what I desired... Please have the honor of publishing an answer on this and I'll gladly accept; I don't think I deserve to publish this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the cursor is on the first line, then delete the first line by using <kbd>Delete</kbd>, thereby moving the table (and everything that comes after) up one line.